# Thread synchronization in Lisp

Tags: multithreading, lisp, common-lisp, thread-synchronization

Inside a `progn` I have to make sure that `asdf:run-shell-command` (which need time to be processed) has finished before the next step.

```
(progn
    (do-data-for-next-command)
    (asdf:run-shell-command ...)
    (do-something-when-previous-command-is-done))
```

Note that I use Clozure CL and SBCL.

I guess that I have to manage with threads. I found something like `make-lock` in Clozure CL documentation, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a recent ASDF, use [run-program](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Some-Utility-Functions.html#index-run_002dprogram). It waits for completion.

> `run-program` takes a command argument that is either a list of a program name or path and its arguments, or a string to be executed by a shell. It spawns the command, **waits for it to return**, verifies that it exited cleanly ..., and optionally captures and processes its output. It accepts many keyword arguments to configure its behavior.

Comment: For some reason `ccl:run-program` does not work with my arguments. 
`asdf:run-shell-command` should work with the argument `:wait t` (which is the default value).
The problem is that my shell command initiates a process in background. This process needs time to be operate (the time to open a datagram socket).
Anyway, waiting a real solution I did a hack by including (sleep 10) juste after `run-shell-command`.